# Rails RuntimeError: can't modify immutable cached environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a "can't modify immutable cached environment" error when trying to run console:

```
11: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
10: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:75:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
 9: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
 8: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
 7: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
 6: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
 5: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
 4: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
 3: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/xray-rails-0.3.2/lib/xray/engine.rb:77:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 2: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:51:in `register_preprocessor'
 1: from /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:211:in `register_config_processor'


/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:66:in `config=': can't modify immutable cached environment (RuntimeError)
```

I solved it with the solution below (a certain gem was causing the issue).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the xray-rails gem:

```
 gem 'xray-rails'
```

Removing that fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while I was running tests on a Docker container and one of the factories had an error. Fixing that error would allow running the specs

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

SyntaxError:
  /spec/factories/apk_snapshots.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
        scan_status: ApkSnapshot.scan_statuses['sc
                    ^
  /spec/factories/apk_snapshots.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```